# Crosswords: Maximum number of words in an n×n grid

Tags: calculation-puzzle, combinatorics, strategy, crosswords

What is the maximum number of "words spaces" that can be in an n×n crossword, based on the placement of the shaded squares.

Some limitations

- No word can be less than 3 spaces in length
- Every cell in the grid must be part of an across AND a down

For example, for a 3×3 grid, there are 6 maximum words (3 downs, 3 acrosses), because no shaded squares can be added without creating word spaces of less than length 3.

Any discussion helps. Thanks

Comment: Do words in the same row/column need to be separated by a shaded square?

Comment: @hexomino: How else would "word spaces" be delimited?

Comment: @DanielMathias Possibly with horizontal/vertical bars, see for example this style: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99641/its-in-the-past-in-the-past

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kevin Ferland and I have a paper on this:
*Maximal Crossword Grids*, **Journal of Combinatorial Mathematics and Combinatorial Computing** (Feb. 2019)

See also [OEIS A243826](https://oeis.org/A243826), which has a link to Ferland's earlier paper.

Here are a summary table and selected examples from
[*Illustrations of solutions for 3 ≤ n ≤ 50* <sub>PDF</sub>](https://oeis.org/A243826/a243826_1.pdf)
at [OEIS A243826](https://oeis.org/A243826).

$$ \small\begin{array}{rccc|rccc|rccc}
n & \large{ W = \atop \textsf{words} } & 2n \left\lfloor{n+1 \over 4}\right\rfloor & W \over { 2n \left\lfloor{n+1 \over 4}\right\rfloor } &
n & \large{ W = \atop \textsf{words} } & 2n \left\lfloor{n+1 \over 4}\right\rfloor & W \over { 2n \left\lfloor{n+1 \over 4}\right\rfloor } &
n & \large{ W = \atop \textsf{words} } & 2n \left\lfloor{n+1 \over 4}\right\rfloor & W \over { 2n \left\lfloor{n+1 \over 4}\right\rfloor }
\\ \hline
  3 &\boldsymbol{   6 }&   6 &  1  &  19 &\boldsymbol{ 158 }& 190 & .83 &  35 &\boldsymbol{  570 }&  630 & .90 \\
  4 &\boldsymbol{   8 }&   8 &  1  &  20 &\boldsymbol{ 184 }& 200 & .92 &  36 &\boldsymbol{  616 }&  648 & .95 \\
  5 &\boldsymbol{  10 }&  10 &  1  &  21 &\boldsymbol{ 198 }& 210 & .94 &  37 &\boldsymbol{  642 }&  666 & .96 \\
  6 &\boldsymbol{  12 }&  12 &  1  &  22 &\boldsymbol{ 220 }& 220 &  1  &  38 &\boldsymbol{  684 }&  684 &  1  \\
  7 &\boldsymbol{  22 }&  28 & .79 &  23 &\boldsymbol{ 236 }& 276 & .86 &  39 &\boldsymbol{  712 }&  780 & .91 \\
  8 &\boldsymbol{  28 }&  32 & .88 &  24 &\boldsymbol{ 268 }& 288 & .93 &  40 &\boldsymbol{  764 }&  800 & .95 \\
  9 &\boldsymbol{  32 }&  36 & .89 &  25 &\boldsymbol{ 284 }& 300 & .95 &  41 &\boldsymbol{  792 }&  820 & .97 \\
 10 &\boldsymbol{  40 }&  40 &  1  &  26 &\boldsymbol{ 312 }& 312 &  1  &  42 &\boldsymbol{  840 }&  840 &  1  \\
 11 &\boldsymbol{  50 }&  66 & .76 &  27 &\boldsymbol{ 332 }& 378 & .88 &  43 &\boldsymbol{  872 }&  946 & .92 \\
 12 &\boldsymbol{  64 }&  72 & .89 &  28 &\boldsymbol{ 368 }& 392 & .94 &  44 &\boldsymbol{  928 }&  968 & .96 \\
 13 &\boldsymbol{  72 }&  78 & .92 &  29 &\boldsymbol{ 388 }& 406 & .96 &  45 &\boldsymbol{  960 }&  990 & .97 \\
 14 &\boldsymbol{  84 }&  84 &  1  &  30 &\boldsymbol{ 420 }& 420 &  1  &  46 &\boldsymbol{ 1012 }& 1012 &  1  \\
 15 &\boldsymbol{  96 }& 120 & .80 &  31 &\boldsymbol{ 442 }& 496 & .89 &  47 &\boldsymbol{ 1046 }& 1128 & .93 \\
 16 &\boldsymbol{ 116 }& 128 & .91 &  32 &\boldsymbol{ 484 }& 512 & .95 &  48 &\boldsymbol{ 1108 }& 1152 & .96 \\
 17 &\boldsymbol{ 126 }& 136 & .93 &  33 &\boldsymbol{ 506 }& 528 & .96 &  49 &\boldsymbol{ 1142 }& 1176 & .97 \\
 18 &\boldsymbol{ 144 }& 144 &  1  &  34 &\boldsymbol{ 544 }& 544 &  1  &  50 &\boldsymbol{ 1200 }& 1200 &  1  \\
\end{array}$$

[image]

Comment: Glad to append such a fascinating and handsome series of examples, @RobPratt.
Your results are truly compelling.
That optimality can be achieved for every 4th $n$ is very interesting.
How the patterns behave along the edges of grids' quadrants
is downright enjoyable.